# Cannot realize click and focus on dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the situation. I've a table  with chat

```
<table id="shoutbox_table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0">
<tr id="shoutbox_msgs"><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

and a field to post a message

```
<input type="text" id="shoutbox_message" style="text-decoration:underline;padding:2px 0;width:90%" onkeypress="var k = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which; if (k == 13) Shoutbox_SentMsg('22d0963fed98aac17f50112871dd7e81');" />
```

Content into table loads via XMLHttpRequest, and chat looks like this

```
<table id="shoutbox_table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr id="shoutbox_row43"><td nowrap="nowrap" style="text-align:right" class="smalltext" valign="top"><a href="http://phoenix-warriors.ru/index.php?action=profile;u=270" target="_blank" style="color:#ff009c">Mrak07</a> <span style="color:#FFFFFF">[22 Фев 08:05]</span>:</td><td style="text-align:left" class="smalltext" valign="top"><span style="">4 день донатная рарка(</span></td></tr>
<tr id="shoutbox_row44"><td nowrap="nowrap" style="text-align:right" class="smalltext" valign="top"><a href="http://phoenix-warriors.ru/index.php?action=profile;u=270" target="_blank" style="color:#ff009c">Mrak07</a> <span style="color:#FFFFFF">[22 Фев 08:55]</span>:</td><td style="text-align:left" class="smalltext" valign="top"><span style=""><a href="http://berserktcg.ru/?gift=fb515520-1fb5-473f-8ff8-edb83a4855b2" target="_blank">http://berserktcg.ru/?gift=fb515520-1fb5-473f-8ff8-edb83a4855b2</a></span></td></tr>
<tr id="shoutbox_row45"><td nowrap="nowrap" style="text-align:right" class="smalltext" valign="top"><a href="http://phoenix-warriors.ru/index.php?action=profile;u=270" target="_blank" style="color:#ff009c">Mrak07</a> <span style="color:#FFFFFF">[22 Фев 09:12]</span>:</td><td style="text-align:left" class="smalltext" valign="top"><span style="">играю телохранами сливаюсь от всех подряд</span></td></tr>
<tr id="shoutbox_row46"><td nowrap="nowrap" style="text-align:right" class="smalltext" valign="top"><a href="http://phoenix-warriors.ru/index.php?action=profile;u=525" target="_blank" style="color:#00AC14;">Безуминка</a> <span style="color:#FFFFFF">[22 Фев 09:17]</span>:</td><td style="text-align:left" class="smalltext" valign="top"><span style="">привет всем</span></td></tr><tr id="shoutbox_msgs"></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I need - when clicking on this Mrak07 - grab the anchor and paste it to

I wrote this code

```
$('#shoutbox_table').on('click', 'a[target="_blank"]', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var sayto=$(this).text();
$("#shoutbox_message").val("["+sayto+"], "+$("#shoutbox_message").val());
    $("#shoutbox_message").focus();
});
```

It is perfectly works on static content - https://jsfiddle.net/Reset5/j5qzt0uj/9/ but doesn't work on forum. Please point me to solve this.

P.S. Forum has jquery-1.10.1.min.js

P.S.2 Actually even the alert in not fired with this code.

Comment: Show us how the table is populated with the content loaded via AJAX.

Comment: It is in this section - "Content into table loads via XMLHttpRequest, and chat looks like this" - <tr id="shoutbox_row...."></tr> inserted via AJAX

Comment: And you’re sure it only inserts the new table row, and does not replace the whole table?

Comment: Sure sir, first code block is copied from source code, but 3rd is copied from DOM.